# Windows Phone - Rate & Review Command

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app.  On WP8.1 when getting the user to rate/review my app I use the following command:

```
new MarketplaceReviewTask().Show();
```

This takes the user to the rate/review option for my app on the Windows Store app. However, this command does not work on WP10 - it just hangs, then eventually goes to the main entry point for the store. Now I also have this app on PC as a Windows 8.1 RT app. Here I use a different command:

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-windows-store:REVIEW?PFN=Microsoft.CityArtSearch_8wekyb3d8bbwe"));
```

I can use this command on my phone app and it works fine on WP10. However, on WP8.1 it opens the **Xbox Music App** for some reason. Does anyone know of a way to to use the second command successfully on WP8.1? Is there now a different URI?

Answer (score 2):

When you are using Windows Phone 8.1 non silverlight the following code will work

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(string.Format("ms-windows-store:reviewapp?appid={0}", appID)));
```

Now, what is appID? I took me a while to figure this out. It's not something you find in the package manifest file (at least for me).

To get your specific appID, log into your Windows Dev Account, go to Dashboard, navigate to your app, then go to `App Management` and `App Identity`. At the bottom you can see a URL for Windows Phone 8.1 and earlier with an appID part. This is your appID for the launcher command.

[image: Retrieve app id via Windows Dev Center]

This works for me on WinRT 8.1. But I have no idea how to get this appID if your app isn't uploaded to the Windows Dev Center yet. According to the certification rules of Microsoft it shouldn't be possible to get your app certified if there is no possibility to review it from inside the app as far as I remember. But at least in my situation they weren't that careful when certifying my app :)

However this solution does probably not solve your issue with the OS version check.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following syntax:

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-windows-store:reviewapp?appid=" + appid));
```

Where appid is the Package name (PhoneProductId) from the Package.appxmanifest.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick! I was getting by with programmatically checking the OSVersion and then selecting the appropriate command based on it it being WP8.1 or WP10. But yours is the better solution.

Comment: This solution now, no longer works :( I'm falling back to checking OS version for which command to use.